# Why is my code throwing [$http:badreq] error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to fetch some JSON data using the given URL. I can't understand why it's not working. I went through angular docs and other resources but as I am new to angular, am finding it difficult to find out the error. Can someone help me, please?

My code.

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.controller('mainController', ['$http', function ($http){
var self = this;


this.matches = [];
console.log(this.matches);

this.basrUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2015-16/en.1.json";

this.loadAllMatches = function(){   
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: self.baseUrl,
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response);
        self.matches = response.data.matches;
        console.log(self.matches);

      },function errorCallback(response){
        alert("Some Error occurred, check the console");
        console.log(response);

      });
    }   
}]);
```

Comment: `basrUrl` vs `baseUrl` perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is probably not getting the right baseUrl, confirm that the self.baseUrl returns an actual link because you probably misspelled. this.basrurl and self.baseurl

Comment: I checked the URL using RESTClient. It returns the data.

Comment: Yup, got my error. It's working fine. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo:

`this.basrUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2015-16/en.1.json";`

`basrUrl`

Actual usage:

`url: self.baseUrl`

Comment: yeah, I keep on making this spelling mistakes, thanks for helping me :)